# How to parse this URL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, url

How to parse this URL in Flutter and get pure variable data?

https://example.com/#tgWebAppData=query_id%3DAAGug8ssAAAAAK6DyyyZuqxK%26user%3D%257B%2522id%2522%253A751535022%252C%2522first_name%2522%253A%2522Sergei%2522%252C%2522last_name%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522username%2522%253A%2522svlobachev%2522%252C%2522language_code%2522%253A%2522ru%2522%257D%26auth_date%3D1687500108%26hash%3Db0fc44025378ae5fc6e5b1529aa9265c3b15ee9902ac2cbad84ee651409cfee0&tgWebAppVersion=6.7&tgWebAppPlatform=android&tgWebAppThemeParams=%7B%22bg_color%22%3A%22%23181819%22%2C%22secondary_bg_color%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C%22text_color%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22hint_color%22%3A%22%237d7d7d%22%2C%22link_color%22%3A%22%2357a7e0%22%2C%22button_color%22%3A%22%2350a8eb%22%2C%22button_text_color%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D

Comment: You might be looking for [/networking/fetch-data](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
final URL =
    "https://example.com/#tgWebAppData=query_id%3DAAGug8ssAAAAAK6DyyyZuqxK%26user%3D%257B%2522id%2522%253A751535022%252C%2522first_name%2522%253A%2522Sergei%2522%252C%2522last_name%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522username%2522%253A%2522svlobachev%2522%252C%2522language_code%2522%253A%2522ru%2522%257D%26auth_date%3D1687500108%26hash%3Db0fc44025378ae5fc6e5b1529aa9265c3b15ee9902ac2cbad84ee651409cfee0&tgWebAppVersion=6.7&tgWebAppPlatform=android&tgWebAppThemeParams=%7B%22bg_color%22%3A%22%23181819%22%2C%22secondary_bg_color%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C%22text_color%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22hint_color%22%3A%22%237d7d7d%22%2C%22link_color%22%3A%22%2357a7e0%22%2C%22button_color%22%3A%22%2350a8eb%22%2C%22button_text_color%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D";

String uri = Uri.decodeComponent(URL);
uri = Uri.decodeComponent(uri);
print(uri);
```